# Not understanding this background process of Proc

Tags: ruby, proc

I came across solving a problem and my solution was below.

```
    class Array
      def my_each(&prc)
        prc ||= proc { |ele| puts ele }
        idx = 0
        while idx < self.length
          prc.call(self[idx])
          idx += 1
        end
        self
      end
    end

    puts ["apple", "banana"].my_each {}   #=> ["apple, "banana"]
```

My question is, why isn't the result

```
    #=>"apple" 
    #=>"banana"  
    #=>["apple", "banana"]
```

is this because my block isn't run and only the self was returned?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is simple: your block is empty, it doesn't do anything.

If you want to print the individual items, you need to either print them in the block:

```
puts ["apple", "banana"].my_each {|el| puts el }
# apple
# banana
# apple
# banana
```

or don't pass a block so that your default block fires:

```
puts ["apple", "banana"].my_each
# apple
# banana
# apple
# banana
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing it up, I think I thought passing in an empty block like {} would make the prc in prc or equal statement false, now I understand